# How to use php get post meta tag in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm creating a date javascript code, but I wanted to put custom meta tags that I created in php in that javascript code.

For example, for sunday hours, I code this so that when one create a post, a meta box is displayed under the post for one to enter sunday hours.

```
<label for="meta-text" class="prfx-row-title"><?php _e( 'Sunday Hours', 'prfx-textdomain' )?></label>
<input type="text" name="sundayhours" id="sundayhours" value="<?php if ( isset ( $prfx_stored_meta['sundayhours'] ) ) echo $prfx_stored_meta['sundayhours'][0]; ?>" />
```

and then I use `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sundayhours', true); ?>` in html/php page. But since I'm creating a Javascript code for the week hours:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var dayOfWeek2 = (new Date).getDay();
var hours2 = [<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sundayhours', true); ?>, // Sunday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Monday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Tuesday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Wednesday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Thursday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Friday
             "Today: 8:00am to 5:00pm"];  // Saturday
var todaysHours2 = hours2[dayOfWeek2];
document.getElementById("hours2").innerHTML = todaysHours2;

});
```

As you can see, I tried to add the  to the Sunday Hours slot.

However, I don't know if it'll work because dreamweaver had a red warning sign next to the code saying something like that "Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'. What is the right way of adding php get meta tag to javascript file?

Comment: For cleanliness you should probably not have your html/php/js in the same file. If you put this javascript in its own file you could easily retrieve the value you need by using AJAX, which is a pretty standard way to retrieve PHP values in JS. But for this method, trying putting in putting the php portion in quotations. That has worked for me in the past when I tested things like this.

Comment: They are all in their own separate files and if you know wordpress, the wordpress pages are php files with html code inside the php pages. The question I'm asking is how to use the data from the php meta tag in this javascript code.

Comment: AH ok yeah thats why your code wont work since you cant use php tags in a .js file, at least not to my knowledge. You're probably going to have to use a GET or AJAX request to get the value you need. They can be tricky when you're new to it but once you get the hang of them you'll find them to be very useful.

Comment: so GET like this?
var hours2 = [get("<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sundayhours', true); ?>"), // Sunday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Monday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Tuesday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Wednesday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Thursday
             "Today: 8:00am to 9:00pm",   // Friday
             "Today: 8:00am to 5:00pm"];  // Saturday
var todaysHours2 = hours2[dayOfWeek2];
document.getElementById("hours2").innerHTML = todaysHours2;

Comment: No no. By GET I mean an AJAX request. If you're not familiar maybe this article should help you get it set up: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/. Basically you need to write a function in php that returns the value you need. Then you use ajax to call this function, and consequently retrieve the value you need in the response. The article I linked should give you an idea, but I would strongly recommend reading up on AJAX as they are essential to modern web development. may look scary at first but becomes 2nd nature with a little practice.

Comment: Have a look at wp_localize_script() considering it's in WP. It's brilliant!

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script